# Variable has incomplete type 'ParamBlockRec' (aka 'ParamBlockRec')

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm frustated by an error (in title) I'm getting when compiling a c++ project in XCode.

This is the line of code:

```
ParamBlockRec pb;
```

That's all. I don't know what could be wrong with it.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the header file in which `ParamBlockRec` has its complete definition. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I already did that with `#include </System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Files.h>`. But the error still occures.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß: then it seems you're missing the namespace.

Comment: I'm pretty lost right know. What's the namespace of ParamBlockRec?

Comment: @JohannesKlauß: You don't know namespace? Or you don't know in which namespace the type is defined? Why don't you open the header file, and see it?

Comment: ParamBlockRec is from Carbon, which is plain C, which in turn doesn't do namespace. :)